# Convert to currency format

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a built in function of JavaScript to convert a string into a currency format?

For example

```
var a = '1234';
a.convertToCurrency();   // return $1,234
```

**UPDATE**

Please note that I want the function to return the currency to include the US comma to group digits.

Comment: FWIW there is now a built in function in JavaScript that does this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat, which works in Node as well - as of 0.12

Answer (score 14):

> I have decided to completely rewrite example I did in 2009. **Please check [diff](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1726759/revisions) if interested in older version**. In order to achieve functionality like previous answer, I have extracted a part of the `Money` library I am working on.
>
> *I also don't remember why I have recreated `toFixed` last time as that method was already present. This time it is not included.*

Instead of messing with `String` and `Number` objects in javascript, like last time, I am creating new, `Money`, object.

```
(function() {
  window.Money = (function() {

    Money.prototype.amount = 0.0;
    Money.prototype.fraction_count = 2;
    Money.prototype.fraction_separator = ",";
    Money.prototype.separate_thousands = true;
    Money.prototype.symbol = "€";
    Money.prototype.symbol_position = "front";
    Money.prototype.symbol_spacing = false;
    Money.prototype.thousands_separator = ".";

    function Money(amount, options) {
      var o;
      if (options == null) {
        options = {};
      }
      for (o in options) {
        this[o] = options[o];
      }
      amount = parseFloat(amount);
      if (!isNaN(amount)) {
        this.amount = amount;
      }
      this.format();
    }

    Money.prototype.format = function() {
      this.string_amount = this.amount.toFixed(this.fraction_count);
      if (this.separate_thousands) {
        this.string_amount = this.separateThousands();
      }
      return this.string = this.addSymbol();
    };

    Money.prototype.separateThousands = function() {
      var after_dot, before_dot, pattern, _ref;
      _ref = this.string_amount.split("."), before_dot = _ref[0], after_dot = _ref[1];
      pattern = /(-?\d+)(\d{3})/;
      while (pattern.test(before_dot)) {
        before_dot = before_dot.replace(pattern, "$1" + this.thousands_separator + "$2");
      }
      return [before_dot, after_dot].join(this.fraction_separator);
    };

    Money.prototype.addSymbol = function() {
      var string;
      string = [this.string_amount];
      string.splice((this.symbol_position === "front" ? 0 : 1), 0, this.symbol);
      return string.join(this.symbol_spacing ? " " : "");
    };

    return Money;

  })();
```

Now, I do need to modify `Number` and/or `String` objects slightly and add `toMoney` method.

```
Number.prototype.toMoney = function(options) {
  return new Money(this, options);
};

String.prototype.toMoney = function(options) {
  return new Money(this, options);
};
```

So, finally, we can convert `String` and/or `Number` to `Money` and write it out as `String` again.

```
x = "1234567890.0987654321".toMoney();
y = 1234567890.0987654321.toMoney({fraction_count: 5, symbol: "$", symbol_position: "back"});

console.log(x);
// Money {amount: 1234567890.0987654, string_amount: "1.234.567.890,10", string: "€1.234.567.890,10"}

console.log(x.string)
// €1.234.567.890,10 

console.log(y);
// Money {fraction_count: 5, symbol: "$", symbol_position: "back", amount: 1234567890.0987654, string_amount: "1.234.567.890,09877"…}

console.log(y.string)
// 1.234.567.890,09877$
```

I think this solution is much better than the last one I wrote. For working example check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQzRZ/).

Comment: Appears to have a bug: 0.5 formats as "0.5", not "0.50" (currency must be to 2 decimals not one)

Comment: I have fixed the fraction place if the decimal doesn't have enough places.
**Change:**
`$A.arr[1] == undefined ? $A._dec = $O.use_fractions.fraction_separator + "0".times($O.use_fractions.fractions) : $A._dec = $O.use_fractions.fraction_separator + $A.arr[1];`

**To:**
`$A.arr[1] == undefined ? $A._dec = $O.use_fractions.fraction_separator + "0".times($O.use_fractions.fractions) : $A._dec = $O.use_fractions.fraction_separator + $A.arr[1] + "0".times($O.use_fractions.fractions - $A.arr[1].length);`

Comment: I did a small rewrite, think this version is better.

Comment: If you set the "fraction_count" to zero, it should remove the "thousands_separator" at the end. You know, you should put this into a Github repo so we can contribute as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = 1234.12;
var c = '$' + a.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: That doesn't add in the "," (commas)

Comment: Your example return $1234.12 but I want it to return $1,234

Comment: Unfortunately it depends on your system settings.

Comment: Do you know how to modify your example to have it include the comma (",") to group the digits?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a lot of work to just parse out a string and figure out where to put the commas.

Here's a little script I put together this morning that will do the trick for whole numbers:

Call the function numberToCurrency and pass your value as (amount), and it will put the commas where they should be.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Number to Money Conversion</title>
<script>
    function numberToCurrency(amount) {

        var thousandsSeparator = ","
        var currencyNum = "";
        var amountString = amount.toString();
        var digits = amountString.split("");

        var countDigits = digits.length;
        var revDigits = digits.reverse();

        for(var i=0; i<countDigits; i++) {
            if ((i%3 == 0) && (i !=0)) {
                currencyNum += thousandsSeparator+revDigits[i];
            } else {
                currencyNum += digits[i];
            }
        };

        var revCurrency = currencyNum.split("").reverse().join("");

        var finalCurrency = "$"+revCurrency;

        return finalCurrency;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
document.write(numberToCurrency('1238868934324'));
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

You can act on this in a loop taking variables as well -- I threw together a stacked bar chart in Raphael that has the tooltips displaying formatted dollar amounts, taken from straight numbers in an array, so I don't have to fiddle with all the quotes 'n' such. Aside from the black bubble backgrounds being progressively mis-aligned when I mouse over the stacks in each bar, it works pretty well - still having trouble with the labels - labeliser seems to have issues. Just a test sample, really, but for converting numbers to currency, it does the trick.

I've also done a script that detects for cents and appends a "0" if there's just one digit after the ".", but I haven't tested that as extensively, and there are numerous different tests I could imagine you'd need to do in addition. I'll post the working copy shortly and you can play with it.

Here's what I did with Raphael: http://lifeistryingtotellyousomething.info/raphael/raphael-stacked-column-demo-2000.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach which accounts for cents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Money Conversion</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function numberToCurrency(amount) {

    var wholeDigits;
    var thousandsSeparator = ","
    var centSeparator = "."
    var currencyNum = "";

    if(amount.indexOf(".") != -1) {
        var hasCents = true;
    } else {
        var hasCents = false;
    }

    if (hasCents == true) {
        var num = amount.split(".");
        var wholeDigits = num[0].split("");
        var centAmount = num[1];
        var centDigits = num[1].split("");

        if (centDigits.length == 0) {
            centDigits += "00";
        }
        if ((centDigits.length > 0) && (centDigits.length < 2)) {
            centDigits += "0";
        }

    } else {
        centDigits = "";
        centSeparator = "";
        wholeDigits = amount.split("");
    }

    var countDigits = wholeDigits.length;

    var revDigits = wholeDigits.reverse();

    for(var i=0; i<countDigits; i++) {
            if ((i%3 == 0) && (i !=0)) {
                currencyNum += thousandsSeparator+revDigits[i];
            } else {
                currencyNum += wholeDigits[i];
            }
    };

    var revCurrency = currencyNum.split("").reverse().join("");

    var finalCurrency = "$"+revCurrency+centSeparator+centAmount;

    return finalCurrency;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">

document.write(numberToCurrency('12326563523.37'));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It does the trick, though it doesn't round the cent amounts or strip off extras past 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

This we did in one of our project long back. I just find out the code . Our application was in asp.net. Function **dollarAmount** does the work

```
function checkNum(data) {      // checks if all characters
        var valid = "0123456789.";     // are valid numbers or a "."
        var ok = 1; var checktemp;
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        checktemp = "" + data.substring(i, i+1);
        if (valid.indexOf(checktemp) == "-1") return 0; }
        return 1;
    }

    function dollarAmount(form, field, appendZero) 
    { 
        Num = "" + eval("document." + form + "." + field + ".value");

        if(Num=="")
        {
            eval("document." + form + "." + field + ".value = '" + 0 + "';");
            return;
        }

        dec = Num.indexOf(".");

        end = ((dec > -1) ? "" + Num.substring(dec,Num.length) : "");

        Num = "" + parseInt(Num);

        var temp1 = "";
        var temp2 = "";
        //var appendZero=1;

        if (checkNum(Num) == 0) {
        //alert("This does not appear to be a valid number.  Please try again.");
        }
        else {

            if(appendZero==1 || end !="")
            {
                if (end.length == 2) end += "0";
                if (end.length == 1) end += "00";
                if (end == "") end += ".00";
            }

        var count = 0;
        for (var k = Num.length-1; k >= 0; k--) {
        var oneChar = Num.charAt(k);
        if (count == 3) {
        temp1 += ",";
        temp1 += oneChar;
        count = 1;
        continue;
        }
        else {
        temp1 += oneChar;
        count ++;
        }
        }
        for (var k = temp1.length-1; k >= 0; k--) {
        var oneChar = temp1.charAt(k);
        temp2 += oneChar;
        }
        temp2 = temp2 + end;
        eval("document." + form + "." + field + ".value = '" + temp2 + "';");
        }
    }
```

We called this function like this

```
txtBox.Attributes.Add("OnBlur", "return DollarAmount('" + txtBox.ID + "',0)");
```

Also after googling I found this links

a) [Use JavaScript to Format Currency within Your Web Page](http://www.web-source.net/web_development/currency_formatting.htm)

b) [Currency Format](http://javascript.internet.com/forms/currency-format.html)

Also I guess that JQuery may have some plugin for serving the purpose
[Currency: an unobstrusive automatic and real time currency conversion](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/3796)

But I doubt if any inbuilt function is available in javascript. Please let me know if you found any. I would love to know.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post. Nonetheless, this worked in for me in my own case:

```
var a = parseInt("1234");
console.log("$"+number_format(a));

var number_format = function(total) {
   return total.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
};
```