# Javascript showing in dollars

Tags: javascript, dom-events, acrobat

How would I display JavaScript output numbers in dollar format? I.E. $20.00 then $2,000.00 when the number gets larger.
 Ok so sample code.

```
if(this.getField("Account Name RequiredRow1").value !="") {
    event.value = 20;
}
else{
    event.value = "";
}
```

Comment: What is "dollar format"?

Comment: I am assuming he means either $20.00 or 20.00

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert to currency format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718878/convert-to-currency-format)

Comment: So you want two decimal places, and thousands separators, and then prefix a `$` character. Divide and conquer, my friend; programming doesn't care about US dollars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the function that I use..  Basically the same as @Senad's except it adds commas:

```
function(val) {
    var valString = val.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return "$" + valString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function formatCurrency(num) {
    num = isNaN(num) || num === '' || num === null ? 0.00 : num;
    return '$' + parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
}
```

This is the easiest way

Comment: But it doesn't satisfy the requirement for thousands separators.